# barra transparente scroll

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

tengo un codigo que pone transparente la barra del scroll en los navegadores de los telefonos, pero pone transparente ambas, la (x) y la (y) solamente necesito dejar transparente la  barra (x) no logo dar con lo que necesito, como hago?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 2px;height: 2px;} ::-webkit-scrollbar button {width: 0px;height: 0px;} ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background:transparent;border: 0px none transparent; border-radius: 50px;} ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover { background: transparent;} ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {background: transparent;}::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background: transparent; border: 0px none transparent;border-radius: 50px;}::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {background: transparent;}::-webkit scrollbar-track:active {background: transparent;}::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {background: transparent;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a usar la pseudoclase: ***:horizontal*** de esta forma:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la propiedad **Overflow**

Esta siempre tiene como defecto el valor `visible`

```
Sintáxis formal: [ visible | hidden | clip | scroll | auto ]{1,2}
```

**Propiedades**

```
overflow: visible

overflow: hidden

overflow: scroll

overflow: auto

overflow: inherit
```

**Ejemplos**

```css
p {  
     width: 12em;
     border: dotted;
     overflow: visible;   /* Muestra barras si es necesario */ 
}
```

```css
p { 
  overflow: hidden; /* No muestra barras */
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba usando

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```